# Create Tablespace Script in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, scripting, tablespace

I am using the below script for generating a DDL to create tablespaces in the database.

```
select 'create tablespace ' || df.tablespace_name || chr(10)
 || ' datafile ''' || df.file_name || ''' size ' || df.bytes 
 || decode(autoextensible,'N',null, chr(10) || ' autoextend on maxsize ' 
 || maxbytes) 
 || chr(10) 
 || 'default storage ( initial ' || initial_extent 
 || decode (next_extent, null, null, ' next ' || next_extent )
 || ' minextents ' || min_extents
 || ' maxextents ' ||  decode(max_extents,'2147483645','unlimited',max_extents) 
 || ') ;' "Script To Recreate Tablespaces"
 from dba_data_files df, dba_tablespaces t
 where df.tablespace_name=t.tablespace_name;
```

It works good. But when a tablespace contains two datafiles then also it creates seperate command with create tablespace. Simply it creates two create tablespace commands if a tablespace contains two datafiles. Please share your thoughts.

Cheers,

Srinivasan Thirunavukkarasu.

Answer (score 5):

If you're just trying to reverse-engineer an existing tablespace to generate a script, why not just use DBMS_METADATA?

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLESPACE','yourTablespaceNameOfInterest') 
from dual;
```

You can generate one of these statements for each tablespace in the database with a simple wrapper if you want them all.

Comment: Hi,

I think DBMS_METADATA is available only in 10g. Mine is 9i database.

Cheers,

Srinivasan Thirunavukkarasu.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a 9i installation includes DBMS_METADATA - perhaps you don't have permissions on the package?

Comment: Srinivasan, if you were asking about 9i, why did you put 10g in the question title ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET LONG 1000000

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLESPACE','tablespace_name')||';' from dual;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
     dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLESPACE',tablespace_name) 
from
     dba_tablespaces
;
```